# Python 3 — integer remains an integer after str() conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a card game; bear in mind that this code has other issues besides the one I'm asking about here. I included it because I don't know what's causing the problem I'm asking about.

The problem is with `a`, I used it `for a in range` then added 1 to it. The line that is commented out gave errors about it not liking to use integers that way. So to try and solve that I put a into `str` but still kept getting errors which is why I added the otherwise pointless line under that `print(type(a) is str)`. That line always returns false so the conversion obviously didn't work and I'm not sure why. If it has to do with how `a` is created (`for a in range(4):`) I'm not sure what to do about it because the way the code is currently set up I need to use `a` in the line that is currently commented out.

```
import itertools
import random

Draw_Pile=list(range(1,52))
random.shuffle(Draw_Pile)
Player=list()
for c in range(4):
    Player.append(c)
print(Player)

for a in range(4):
    a+=1
    str(a)
    print(type(a) is str)
    print("Player %s drew:"%a)
    for i in range(5):
#        Player[a].append(Draw_Pile[0])
        print(Draw_Pile[1])
    for i in range (5):
        Draw_Pile.pop(0)
```

Comment: @msw - Your edit contains good ideas, but it should be an answer, not an edit. The question should preserve the (not very good) code that the OP wrote, so that other people's responses make sense. I'm going to roll back your edit; please turn it into an answer instead so that the OP can benefit from your good suggestions.

Comment: @rmunn feel free to rollback my edit and answer the question with improved code; I don't care enough to do either. I  did leave the troubled line as is so that I didn't break the answer below.

Comment: @mrunn The code is bad because this is a WIP, I was about to ask how to deal with what I was actually trying to do with the code but I realized that I really should fix this problem first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert `a` to a string, you must do `a = str(a)`

Although, you should probably do something like `a_str = str(a)` , so that you don't lose the original variable.

If the reason you are converting `a` to a string is to print, you could just use `%d` in place of `%s`.

Comment: To expand on this answer: `str(a)` has no effect on the value currently in `a`, it just returns a string made from the value of `a`. If you do `b = str(a)`, then `b` will be a string, but `a` will remain whatever it used to be (an integer in this case).

Comment: Also, if you just want to print the value of a, you can use %d in place of %s and not convert it to a string.

Comment: Also, I don't suggest doing `a = str(a)`. Then you'd have a variable `a` with the same name, that was an integer before that statement and becomes a string after that statement. Although Python allows you to put any type of value into any variable, it's not actually a good idea to change the type of value that a single variable contains. I just answered [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33727911/) where the root cause of the problem was changing the type of a variable from integer to string -- and sure enough, it caused an error. Keep variables the same type, it's a better idea.

Comment: Good point of `%d` vs `%s`. Since the OP is using Python 3, it is a little more natural to let `format` be concerned about differing base types.