# Python if else loop concatenate objects

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a simple Python if else loop but I get an

> error: prev_word += value_in cannot concatenate str and int objects

```
prev_word = 0
print_variable = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()       #strip out carriage return
        key_value = line.split('\t')   #split line, into key and value, returns a list   

        #note: for simple debugging use print statements, ie:  
        curr_word = key_value[0]         #key is first item in list, indexed by 0
        value_in = key_value[1]         #value is 2nd item

    if (value_in == "ABC"):
        print_variable = 1
    else:
        value_in = int(value_in)
        prev_word += value_in
    if (print_variable == 1):
        print( '%s\t%s' % (curr_word, prev_word) )
        print_variable = 0
    prev_word = curr_word
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: It's probably because you cannot concatenate str (prev_word) and int (value_in). Notice how on the preceding line, you coerce value_in to be an int, that's probably why it is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning `prev_word` inside your loop at the very end:

```
prev_word = curr_word
```

After this reassign, `prev_word` which is initialized to an `int` becomes a `str` and this causes your addition to fail.

With the power of dynamic types comes great responsibility. Good variable names are key :)

Answer (score 3):

This line is your problem:

```
prev_word = curr_word
```

On your first run through the loop, `prev_word` is the integer 0, and you convert `value_in` to an integer. So when you add `value_in` to `prev_word`, that succeeds because they are both integers. **BUT** you never convert `curr_word` to an integer, so when you set `prev_word` equal to `curr_word`, it becomes a string. And on your *second* time through the loop, `prev_word += value_in` fails because you can't add a string and an  integer (that operation makes no sense).

I suggest not using the name `prev_word` for a variable that's supposed to hold integers, actually. Rename it to `prev_number` or something like that. Because it's obvious why you shouldn't assign `curr_word` to `prev_number`, but it's less obvious why you shouldn't assign `curr_word` to `prev_word`. Even through `prev_word` is really supposed to be a number, at least the way you're using it.

Comment: proper variable names are indeed quite important